# VBA - Keypress for combobox not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

My code got a compile error, but I don't know why.  The objective is to enter a word into TextBoxKeywords and then press enter. The press-enter should trigger the macro called ButtonSearch_Click.  Should be simple, but it gave me a compile error.  Why?

```
Private Sub TextBoxKeywords_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If (Chr(KeyAscii) = 13) Then              '<<<<<<Keyascii 13 = Enter key
        Call ButtonSearch_Click
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: And what is the compiler message? ComboBox is in the same module as the button?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `If KeyAscii= 13 Then`?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator. That is correct,but doesn't forces a compiler error.

Comment: It may not, but correcting errors you *can* identify is the first step in discovering those less obvious.

Comment: Also, why are you using `Call`?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator definitely, I missed that ;(

Comment: Is the macro `ButtonSearch_Click` defined in the same scope as this code?